Bug ytdl-core and m3u8stream in React
Here's my code, and no matter how many different variants I test, I always get the same error in react (jsx), whereas in a node (js) file it works perfectly.
Thanks in advance for your help
My code :
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ytdl from 'ytdl-core';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <GetAudio urlVideo="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NeTQZ2pLs7k&t" />
    </>
  );
}

function GetAudio({urlVideo}) {
  const [audio, setAudio] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAudio = async () => {
      try {
        const videoInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(urlVideo);
        const audioFormats = ytdl.filterFormats(videoInfo.formats, "audioonly");
        setAudio(audioFormats[0].url);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Une erreur s'est produite :", error);
        setAudio("");
      }
    };

    fetchAudio();

  }, [urlVideo]);

  return (
    <audio controls src={audio} />
  );
}

export default App;


The error :
Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at node_modules/m3u8stream/dist/m3u8-parser.js (ytdl-core.js?t=1712152461068&v=8e7b307c:2716:45)
    at __require (chunk-Y2F7D3TJ.js?v=8e7b307c:3:50)
    at node_modules/m3u8stream/dist/index.js (ytdl-core.js?t=1712152461068&v=8e7b307c:3114:41)
    at __require (chunk-Y2F7D3TJ.js?v=8e7b307c:3:50)
    at node_modules/ytdl-core/lib/info-extras.js (ytdl-core.js?t=1712152461068&v=8e7b307c:3279:30)
    at __require (chunk-Y2F7D3TJ.js?v=8e7b307c:3:50)
    at node_modules/ytdl-core/lib/info.js (ytdl-core.js?t=1712152461068&v=8e7b307c:3748:18)
    at __require (chunk-Y2F7D3TJ.js?v=8e7b307c:3:50)
    at node_modules/ytdl-core/lib/index.js (ytdl-core.js?t=1712152461068&v=8e7b307c:4101:19)
    at __require (chunk-Y2F7D3TJ.js?v=8e7b307c:3:50)

My code is supposed to retrieve an audio file from a youtube video and link it to an audio player on the page.

Related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72309727/12846804
